# ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "git.exe"; CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I got the error ProcessNotCreatedException: My project
 is fine but my android studio continuously giving the error below. why
 does this error occur.

ERROR

```
ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "git.exe" (in 
directory "C:\Users\Zeeshan\Desktop"): CreateProcess error=2, The system 
cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: are you trying to import project?

Comment: You project is under git, but when you import it, git.exe does not found because you haven't set path of git inside android studio settings.

Comment: No, project is fine but i'm getting this message continuously in event log.

Comment: @Wizard how to set path?. one thing as i said before the my project build fine; this is the error i'm getting in every 4 to 6 mint in my event log.

Comment: You can set it to `Settings > Version Control > Path to Git.exe`